# How to get the worksheet Name using code Name in VSTO c#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm trying to get the worksheet name using the codeName in VSTO using c#. I know it can be done with openxml but is there a way to do it using VSTO?
this is how it can be done in openxml. But i need to do it in  VSTO

`var worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.Where(ws => ws.Worksheet.SheetProperties != null && ws.Worksheet.SheetProperties.CodeName == codeName).FirstOrDefault(); string relationshipId = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart); IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Elements<Sheet>(); var sheet = sheets.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id.HasValue && s.Id.Value == relationshipId); worsheetName = sheet.Name;`

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

Comment: A quick search gives me this [Excel Sheets VSTO link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/working-with-worksheets?view=vs-2019) and from there [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-list-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook?view=vs-2019) where it has exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Yeah it can be done like that Cleptus, but what I wanna do is using the code name. I know how to get it like that in 2nd link. The first link is a VB code. but thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Worksheet.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.name) property returns or sets a string value that represents the object name. To get the currently selected sheet you can use the [Application.ActiveSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activesheet) property which returns an object that represents the active sheet (the sheet on top) in the active workbook or in the specified window or workbook.

```
string sheetName = Application.ActiveSheet.Name;
```

Comment: Yeah I know I can do this but my requirement is to do it using codeName. Thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

Excel.Sheets sheets = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets;

foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in sheets)

{

```
 if (sheet.CodeName.ToLower() == "testtry")

 {

   string sheetname = sheet.Name;

 }
```

}

check, if this helps you ?